# Sobreponer registros en una tabla MySQL desde PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

alguien me ayudaria a hacer que se sobrepongan registros en una misma tabla ya tengo el registro de todo lo que quiero ver si me pueden ayudar es a saber como sobrepongo esos registros.

```
---+--------+----------------+------------+----------+----------+----------+----------       
Id | Nombre |     E-mail     |    Fecha   | Hora de  | Hora de  | Hora de  | Hora de
   |        |                |            | Entrada  | Comida   | Regreso  | Salida 
---+--------+----------------+------------+----------+----------+----------+----------       
28 | Carlos | Carlos90@gmail | 2008-07-17 | 00:37:42 | 00:00:00 | 00:00:00 | 00:00:00           
29 | Carlos | Carlos90@gmail | 2008-07-17 | 00:00:00 | 00:00:00 | 00:00:00 | 00:37:49   
---+--------+----------------+------------+----------+----------+----------+----------
```

Mi duda es si alguien sabe como hacer que el registro de hora entrada y hora de salida, sean un mismo registro, a continuación comparto el código de hora de entrada espero y puedan ayudarme.

```php
include "../Funciones/Conexion.php";
$mysqli = inicio();

$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$fecha = date('d/m/y');  
$hora = date('H:i:s');


$sql = "INSERT INTO chequeo (nombre,email,fecha,hora)
        VALUES ('$nombre','$email','$fecha','$hora');";

$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
if ($query){
  echo "<script>alert(\"Exito al registrar.\"); </script>";
  echo "<script>location.href='../Usuario.php'</script>";
} else {
  echo "<script>alert(\"Error al registrar\"); </script>";
  echo "<script>location.href='../Usuario.php'</script>";
```

Tengo ademas este otro donde hace el de salida alguien puede ayudarme a como juntarlos para que se sobrepongan

```php
include "../Funciones/Conexion.php";
$mysqli = inicio();

$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$fecha = date('d/m/y');  
$horaS = date('H:i:s');


$sql = "INSERT INTO chequeo (nombre,email,fecha,horaS)
        VALUES ('$nombre','$email','$fecha','$horaS');";

$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
if ($query){
  echo "<script>alert(\"Exito al registrar.\"); </script>";
  echo "<script>location.href='../Usuario.php'</script>";
} else {
  echo "<script>alert(\"Error al registrar\"); </script>";
  echo "<script>location.href='../Usuario.php'</script>";
}
```

Lo Que Requiero es que mi registro mas oh menos quede asi

Id | Nombre | E-mail | Fecha | Hora de Entrada| Hora de Comida| Hora de Regreso de Comida | Hora de Salida |

28 | Carlos | Carlos90@gmail | 2008-07-17 | 00:37:42 | 00:00:00 | 00:00:00 | 00:40:20

Answer (score 1):

Sí te he entendido bien lo que quieres hacer es modificar el primer registro cuando una persona sale.

Para hacer eso tienes que utilizar `UPDATE` en sitio de `INSERT` en el segundo codigo.
Despues de SET pones los datos que quieres cambiar, y despues del WHERE pones los datos qur verifican el registro que quieres cambiar

```
<?php

include "../Funciones/Conexion.php";
$mysqli = inicio();

$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$fecha = date('d/m/y');  
$horaS = date('H:i:s');

$sql = "UPDATE chequeo 
SET horaS = '$horaS' 
WHERE nombre = '$nombre' AND email = '$email' AND fecha = '$fecha'";

$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
if ($query){
echo "<script>alert(\"Exito al registrar.\"); </script>";
echo "<script>location.href='../Usuario.php'</script>";
}else{
echo "<script>alert(\"Error al registrar\"); </script>";
echo "<script>location.href='../Usuario.php'</script>";
}
```

Cuando haces programas que utilicen los datos dados del usuario te sugiero utilizar 'prepared statements' para prevenir 'sql injections'. Información: http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Pues no tanto modificar lo que quiero es que cuando de el chequeo de salida se muestre a un lado del chequeo de entrada mas oh menos asi
     
Id | Nombre |     E-mail     |    Fecha   |  | Hora de entrada  | Hora de salida  
      
28 | Carlos | Carlos90@gmail | 2008-07-17 | 00:37:42 | 00:40:35 |